# Adding an external JavaScript file in NetBeans and linking with the index file

Tags: javascript, html, netbeans

I have added a `JavaScript` file into my existing project and referred that in the `HTML` file. The file structure is shown as its in the [attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21Bx5.png). After I run the program, the output does not display what it is supposed to be.
Is there anything wrong with my file tree (how I am adding file into the project) or I am not referring the script the in the correct way?
Here is how my program looks like:

index:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="newjavascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="demo"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

.JS:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 7+9;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be everything is ok with your project structure and refererring to js file inside `index.html`. However, the `demo` paragraph does not display what you want because it can be just not loaded in the time when your `newjavascript.js` is executed. I think you can try to modify it in the following way:

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 7+9;
};
```

Using `onload` function of `window` object you wait until a page (including `demo` paragraph) is loaded - and after it change its content.